# Operation substitution in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I have one task in hand that I am 90% done with it but just don't quite know how to finish it. So the task is as follows : **" Write a non-recursive function which takes a function, and two lists as an input, and returns a third list which contains the result of the function applied on all possible pairs of elements from both input lists."** So I have to get it as below.

```
# cart_fun ( * ) [1;2;2;6;3;9;1] [2;3];; -: int list = [2; 3; 4; 6; 4; 6; 12; 18; 6; 9; 18; 27; 2; 3]
```

My struggle is that I don't know how to make a function substitution. Here is my code.

```
let cart_fun list1 list2 =
  let res = List.fold_left (fun acc x -> List.fold_left (fun acc y -> (x * y) :: acc) acc list2) [] list1
  in List.rev res;;
```

But I would like that in part **(x*y)** the multiplication be given as an argument before the lists.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "function substitution"? You seem to know how to call a function, how to define both a named and anonymous function, and how to pass a function as a parameter to another function. So in `List.fold_left` for example, what do you think the function argument would look like on the "inside", and how do you think the argument could then be used?

Comment: If you really wrote this piece of code that shouldn't be a problem : here the function you apply is just ``fun x y -> x*y`` so it's not hard to generalize this code imo. The only thing I could add to help you is the answer as far as you already did all the job...

Answer (score 0):

Most of the journey has already been made! Well done!
As you can see by using the `fold_left` function, in OCaml (as in other functional languages) you can pass functions as arguments (and even return them), which is why you can provide `fold_left` with an accumulation function. Here is your code:

```ml
let cart_fun list1 list2 =
  let res = List.fold_left (fun acc x -> 
      List.fold_left (fun acc y -> (x * y) :: acc) acc list2) 
   [] list1
  in List.rev res;;
```

Even if the code is very good, let's rephrase it a bit to see it more clearly!

```ml
let cart_fun list1 list2 = 
   let process_list_2 fst_acc = 
        List.fold_left 
           (fun snd_acc y -> (x * y) :: snd_acc) 
           fst_acc 
           list2 
   in 
   let result = List.fold_left (fun acc x -> process_list_2 acc x) [] list1 in 
   List.rev result
```

As you may have realised: `(fun acc x -> process_list_2 acc x)` is, in fact, identical to `process_list_2` so, let's rephase one more time:

```ml
let cart_fun list1 list2 = 
   let process_list_2 fst_acc = 
        List.fold_left 
           (fun snd_acc y -> (x * y) :: snd_acc) 
           fst_acc 
           list2 
   in 
   let result = List.fold_left process_list_2 [] list1 in 
   List.rev result
```

But hey, we want to generalise `cart_fun` in ordrer to have, instead of `cart_fun list1 list2`, we want `cart_fun modifier list1 list2`, where `modifier` is just a function... So, no problem, let's changing this part of the code:

```ml
let cart_fun modifier list1 list2 = 
   let process_list_2 fst_acc = 
        List.fold_left 
           (fun snd_acc y -> (modifier x y) :: snd_acc) 
           fst_acc 
           list2 
   in 
   let result = List.fold_left process_list_2 [] list1 in 
   List.rev result
```

And voila! As you can see, there wasn't much modification required. Just keep in mind that in OCaml, you can consider that a variable will contain a function; which is pretty cool!

Btw, the "general behaviour" that you want to capture looks a lot like what we call "a comprehension" (like in Python and Haskell). And since OCaml 4.10, there is a function in list module which allow you to write easily comprehension : [List.concat_map](https://ocaml.org/api/List.html#VALconcat_map) `val concat_map : ('a -> 'b list) -> 'a list -> 'b list` which has the same effect than mapping over a list of 'a, producing a list of list of b and flatten the list into a list of b.
So you can see your cartesian product as :

```ml
let cart_fun modifier list1 list2 =
    List.concat_map (fun x ->
       List.concat_map (fun y -> 
           [modifier x y]
       ) list2 
    ) list1
```

But as you can see... it's not much more readable than before! Fortunately, in addition to passing functions as arguments, OCaml also allows you to describe your own operators. For example, here we could describe an operator to simplify the chaining of `concat_map` which we would randomely call...  `>>=` :

```ml
let (>>=) list f = List.concat_map f list

let cart_fun modifier list1 list2 = 
   list1 >>= fun x ->
   list2 >>= fun y -> [modifier x y]
```

Awesome, can we go deeper in the readability ? Of course, since OCaml 4.08, you can define `let` operators. So defining your own `let` with a suffix. For example, here, let's define `let*` (which will be exactly the same of `>>=`)

```ml
let (let*) list f = List.concat_map f list
(* So `let* x = l in g x` is the same of `l >>= fun x -> g x` *)
```

nice no?

And now, we can rewrite our example:

```ml
let cart_fun modifier list1 list2 = 
   let* x = list1 in 
   let* y = list2 in 
   [modifier x y]
```

And voila ! Even:

```ml
let cart_fun modifier list1 list2 = 
   let process_list_2 fst_acc = 
        List.fold_left 
           (fun snd_acc y -> (modifier x y) :: snd_acc) 
           fst_acc 
           list2 
   in 
   let result = List.fold_left process_list_2 [] list1 in 
   List.rev result
```

Is "more direct" I think it is nice to see how OCaml is expressive!

Answer (score 0):

`List.concat_map` provides a convenient way to solve this problem. We can use it to generate a list of tuples, and then map over those to multiply them.

```
# lst1
  |> List.concat_map @@ fun a -> List.map (fun b -> (a, b)) lst2
  |> List.map @@ fun (a, b) -> a * b;;
- : int list = [2; 3; 4; 6; 4; 6; 12; 18; 6; 9; 18; 27; 2; 3]
```

Or we can just skip the middle man.

```
# lst1
  |> List.concat_map @@ fun a -> List.map (fun b -> a * b) lst2;;
- : int list = [2; 3; 4; 6; 4; 6; 12; 18; 6; 9; 18; 27; 2; 3]
```

We can also generalize this for any function which takes two arguments of the correct types.

```
# let cart_apply f lst1 lst2 =
    List.(
      lst1 
      |> concat_map 
         @@ fun a -> map (fun b -> f a b) lst2
    );;
val cart_apply : ('a -> 'b -> 'c) -> 'a list -> 'b list -> 'c list = <fun>
# cart_apply ( * ) lst1 lst2;;
- : int list = [2; 3; 4; 6; 4; 6; 12; 18; 6; 9; 18; 27; 2; 3]
```